# Simple Pie 1.3 Keep Original pubDate?

Tags: php, simplepie

I'm using Simple Pie 1.3 for a simple news stream.

Sometimes websites, like ESPN, will update stories constantly. This changes the pubDate and pushes them to the top of my feed.

Is there anyway to check if the story link is already present in the cache?

That way I can just ignore it and keep the story's original pubDate.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an exhausting search it turns out that the answer was right under my nose:

http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/how_to_display_previous_feed_items_like_google_reader

Just have to store/check the entries against a database.

Good for anyone else who has the same question.

Enjoy.